# How can I create a stacked bar chart with Charts.JS that displays relative rather than absolute values?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, bar-chart, chart.js2

I am creating a stacked bar chart with Charts.JS that looks fairly good:

[image]

What I need, though, is for each bar to completely fill the grid, and for the green value to be a percentage, not an absolute value, and for the red value in the same way to be 100% - whatever % the green value is.

IOW, for the values shown in the screenshot above, I need each bar to traverse the entire width and, using the top bar as an example, the text "labeled" onto the green portion should be "99%"

The "99%" label should take the place of the "17,724", and the "170" should completely disappear.

This is the data used currently:

```js
var priceComplianceData = {
    labels: [
        "Bix Produce", "Capitol City", "Charlies Portland", "Costa Fruit and Produce",
        "Get Fresh Sales",
        "Loffredo East", "Loffredo West", "Paragon", "Piazza Produce"
    ],
    datasets: [
    {
        label: "Price Compliant",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(34,139,34,0.5)",
        hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(34,139,34,1)",
        data: [17724, 5565, 3806, 5925, 5721, 6635, 14080, 9027, 25553]
    },
    {
        label: "Non-Compliant",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)",
        hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)",
        // The vals below have been multiplied by 10 (a 0 appended) so that the values are at least visible to the naked eye
        data: [170, 10, 180, 140, 30, 10, 50, 100, 10]
    }
    ]
}
```

...and then it's added to the chart like so:

```js
var priceComplianceOptions = {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [
{
    stacked: true
}
        ],
        yAxes: [
{
    stacked: true
}
        ]
    },
    tooltips: {
        enabled: false
    }
};

var ctxBarChart = $("#priceComplianceBarChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
var priceBarChart = new Chart(ctxBarChart,
{
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: priceComplianceData,
    options: priceComplianceOptions
});
```

The thing that comes to mind is to change the data like so:

```js
datasets: [
{
    label: "Price Compliant",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(34,139,34,0.5)",
    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(34,139,34,1)",
    data: [99.0, 99.2, 99.4, 98.9, 99.1, 99.5, 99.6, 99.2, 99.7]
},
{
    label: "Non-Compliant",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)",
    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)",
    data: [1.0, 0.8, 0.6, 1.1, 0.9, 0.5, 0.4, 0.8, 0.3]
}
]
```

...and then use the first data value as the one to label the green part with, appending a "%" to it.

Is that a sensible approach? Is there a better way?

### UPDATE

The proposed beforeInit/afterDraw doesn't work; causes my more-or-less acceptable charts:

[image]

...to get more hosed up than a haywire firehouse:

[image]

...even though I added this as the first line in both functions:

```
if (chartInstance.id !== 1) return;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is actually quite good, but as you declared in your question, it won't be dynamic and then won't work with every chart of this type.

A way to make it dynamic is to use [Chart.js plugins](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-creating-plugins) where the `beforeInit` event will be handled to edit the data to fit your percentage problem, and where the `afterDraw` event will be handled to write the percentage over the bar :

```js
Chart.pluginService.register({

    // This event helps to edit the data in our datasets to fit a percentage scale
    beforeInit: function(chartInstance) {

        // We first get the total of datasets for every data
        var totals = [];
        chartInstance.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
            for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
                var total = 0;
                chartInstance.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
                    total += dataset.data[i];
                });
                totals.push(total);
            }
        });

        // And use it to calculate the percentage of the current data
        chartInstance.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
            for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
                // This ----------¬     is useful to add it as a string in the dataset
                // It solves      V      the problem of values with `.0` at decimals
                dataset.data[i] = '' + (dataset.data[i] / totals[i]) * 100;
            }
        });
    },

    // This event allows us to add the percentage on the bar
    afterDraw: function(chartInstance) {

        // We get the canvas context
        var ctx = chartInstance.chart.ctx;

        // And set the properties we need
        ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(14, 'bold', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
        ctx.fillStyle = '#666';

        // For every dataset ...
        chartInstance.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {

            // If it is not the first dataset, we return now (no action)
            if (dataset._meta[0].controller.index != 0) return;

            // For ervery data in the dataset ...
            for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {

                // We get the model of the data
                var model = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._model;

                // And use it to display the text where we want
                ctx.fillText(parseFloat(dataset.data[i]).toFixed(2) + "%", ((model.base + model.x) / 2), (model.y + model.height / 3));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

---

You can see this code working [on this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2Las02rc/) and here is its result :

[image]

Comment: Please see my Update.